# Why Gradle build fail with java8?

Tags: java, gradle

We have Gradle script it is building multiple projects with different sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility. If my environment variables JAVA_HOME set to jdk7 all the projects are building successfully. Then I changed the JAVA_HOME to jdk8. Now build fail with below errors:

```
 FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

ava.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 51
    Exception Details:
      Location:
        com/test/Tray.<clinit>()V @42: ifnull
      Reason:
        Expected stackmap frame at this location.
      Bytecode:
        0x0000000: 08bd 0063 5903 1264 5359 0412 6553 5905
        0x0000010: 1266 5359 0612 6753 5907 1268 53b3 006a
        0x0000020: 08bd 006c 5903 00b2 0080 c600 09b2 0080
        0x0000030: a700 0c12 82b8 0084 59b3 0080 0053 5904





java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class java/util/UUID could not be instrumented.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:138)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:99)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.JacocoAgent.createRuntime(JacocoAgent.java:128)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.JacocoAgent.init(JacocoAgent.java:74)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.JacocoAgent.premain(JacocoAgent.java:165)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess
        at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1703)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:136)
        ... 10 more
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0
Exception in thread "main" Could not write standard input into: Gradle Test Executor 2.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class java/util/UUID could not be instrumented.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:138)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:99)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.JacocoAgent.createRuntime(JacocoAgent.java:128)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.JacocoAgent.init(JacocoAgent.java:74)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt_6l8m50.JacocoAgent.premain(JacocoAgent.java:165)
        ... 6 more
```

Could you please tel me how to fix this issue with java8?

Comment: Are you using a version of JaCoCo that's compatible with Java 8 (or a version of Gradle that is compatible with JaCoCo)?

Comment: Added the new jacoco versions.(org.jacoco.agent-0.7.4.201502262128 and org.jacoco.ant-0.7.4.201502262128). Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to play around with your version of JaCoCo and/or ASM according to [this](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/74). It's a known issue going back to about 2013. Go to the maven search site, find the latest versions and push your test dependencies to the latest available ones and see if that fixes it.

Comment: True. This seems to be a known issue. You could have googled for it. https://discuss.gradle.org/t/jacoco-java-8-support/4978